# Can Beast Boy turn into cryptids?

Tags: dc, teen-titans, beast-boy

Can Beast Boy turn into a hidden animal, like Bigfoot, Nessie, or Chupacabra?

Comment: Comics-wise or all-scope wise?

Comment: all-scope wise would be good.

Answer (score 16):

For a [single episode in the Teen Titans cartoon](https://teentitans.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beast_Within), he was able to turn into a Sasquatch:

[image]

It's pretty often that we see him transforming into dinosaurs (examples: [Teen Titans cartoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BEBuEbvMn0), [Teen Titans GO cartoon](https://teen-titans-go.fandom.com/wiki/Ghostboy/Gallery?file=Failed_at_robin.png)). This power dates back very far and was mentioned in [this 1982 interview](http://www.titanstower.com/comics-journal-79-marv-wolfman-interview/) with the co-creator of Teen Titans. Although we don't see him transform into a plesiosaur (which is essentially what the Loch Ness Monster is supposed to be), there's no reason I see he couldn't.

In the comic Teen Titans Go! #36, he transforms into a Gordanian, a type of alien:

[image]

In this comic Robin says that "Animals are [Beast Boy's] thing, but he's taken on other forms... Not without a lot of effort".

In the cartoon [Teen Titans GO!](https://teen-titans-go.fandom.com/wiki/Friendship) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdMkP_V43iI)), he tries to turn into a pegasus but becomes this instead:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe the creature is ever named in that episode. I always thought it was more a werewolf type thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes he can, over the years he has taken the form of creatures that have no bases in the animal kingdom, such as this, [a multi headed creature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smgSD.jpg).

He also can do a partial transformation such as this [centaur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8GK5.jpg).

Here is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/2t8kgk/respect_beast_boy/) of some of his strange non animal transformations.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Boy):

> Beast Boy has the ability to morph and transform into any animal that **he has seen himself or has seen in an illustration** (as is the case when he shapeshifts into an animal such as an extinct dinosaur).

The given citation is Wallace, Dan (2008), "Beast Boy", in Dougall, Alastair, The DC Comics Encyclopedia, London: Dorling Kindersley, p. 39, ISBN 978-0-7566-4119-1

Comment: Did anyone else see the citation author and think "Waller!"  I did, and a moment of panic was my reward. :-)